Automatically disable second display when it is turned off
I have a PC with 2 monitors attached to it. I don't need the second screen all the time, so I quite often turn it off. My problem is, that my desktop environment still thinks it is there: I can move the mouse cursor into the dark void, and sometimes application windows are opening on the black screen. The Display Configuration of my GUI system settings also shows both monitors as active.
How can I tell my desktop environment to automatically disable a monitor, once it is turned off?
(I am on Mint22/Ubuntu 24.04 and Plasma5 (X11, but the behaviour on wayland was no different) as a desktop environment)
UPDATE:
The primary screen is connected with Displayport, the secondary one with HDMI, both on the same discrete graphics adapter.
ddcutil is capable of detecting the power state of the secondary monitor
Both monitors turned on:
$ ddcutil detect
Display 1
   I2C bus:  /dev/i2c-11
   DRM connector:           card2-HDMI-A-4
   EDID synopsis:
      Mfg id:               GSM - Goldstar Company Ltd (LG)
      Model:                LG Ultra HD
      Product code:         23304  (0x5b08)
      Serial number:        
      Binary serial number: 314700 (0x0004cd4c)
      Manufacture year:     2017,  Week: 5
   VCP version:         2.1

Display 2
   I2C bus:  /dev/i2c-13
   DRM connector:           card2-DP-4
   EDID synopsis:
      Mfg id:               BNQ - UNK
      Model:                BenQ PD2700U
      Product code:         32814  (0x802e)
      Serial number:        ET86N02056SL0
      Binary serial number: 16843009 (0x01010101)
      Manufacture year:     2022,  Week: 25
   VCP version:         2.2
$ ddcutil getvcp d6 --display 1
VCP code 0xd6 (Power mode                    ): DPM: On,  DPMS: Off (sl=0x01)
$ ddcutil getvcp d6 --display 2
VCP code 0xd6 (Power mode                    ): DPM: On,  DPMS: Off (sl=0x01)

Only one monitor turned on:
$ ddcutil detect
Invalid display
   I2C bus:  /dev/i2c-11
   DRM connector:           card2-HDMI-A-4
   EDID synopsis:
      Mfg id:               GSM - Goldstar Company Ltd (LG)
      Model:                LG Ultra HD
      Product code:         23304  (0x5b08)
      Serial number:        
      Binary serial number: 314700 (0x0004cd4c)
      Manufacture year:     2017,  Week: 5
   DDC communication failed

Display 1
   I2C bus:  /dev/i2c-13
   DRM connector:           card2-DP-4
   EDID synopsis:
      Mfg id:               BNQ - UNK
      Model:                BenQ PD2700U
      Product code:         32814  (0x802e)
      Serial number:        ET86N02056SL0
      Binary serial number: 16843009 (0x01010101)
      Manufacture year:     2022,  Week: 25
   VCP version:         2.2
$ ddcutil getvcp d6 --display 1
VCP code 0xd6 (Power mode                    ): DPM: On,  DPMS: Off (sl=0x01)
mat@roggen:~$ ddcutil getvcp d6 --display 2
Display not found


Likely the system can't even detect if the monitor is on or off.  And you didn't mention how the display is connected.

@user10489 FWIW, I'm able to detect whether the monitor on screen 1 (here connected over HDMI) is on or off by querying it with ddcutil getvcp d6 --display 1.

You should add that to your question.

I appended the question.

It is possible to turn off the second monitor in software with tools like xrandr and possibly ddcutil, but this bypasses the GUI and may confuse it badly, although this will likely do what you want with the mouse.
A better solution is to use the GUI settings manager to change from "join" mode to "single monitor", and then possibly separately turn off the second monitor.
There may be a KDE plugin to do these steps for you to allow easy toggle back and forth, but as I don't run KDE, I can't test this.
